# Construct View Like Pedantix SwiftUI

Tags: swift, user-interface, swiftui

The problem is quite simple. I want to build something like Pedantix https://cemantix.certitudes.org/pedantix in SwiftUI.

I've this already :
[image]

So, I try to have my RoundedRectangle overlay to totally hide my text. And I want blocks to go at the line if needed, etc. I tried LazyHGrid (actually this), LazyVGrid, custom grid. But no results ...

```
import SwiftUI

struct Word: Identifiable, Equatable {
    var id = UUID()
    var text: String
    var isFramed: Bool
    var isTouched: Bool
}

struct ContentView: View {
@EnvironmentObject var service: Service

let rows = [
    GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 30)),
]

var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { gr in
        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Image(systemName: "arrow.counterclockwise.circle")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 24)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            service.loadRandomMovies(page: 1, completion: { _ in
                                service.loadMovie(id: service.randomMovieId ?? 0, completion: { _ in })
                                service.loadCredits(id: service.randomMovieId ?? 0, completion: { _ in })
                            })
                        }
                }
                HStack {
                    VStack {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                            .frame(width: 150, height: 250)
                    }
                    .padding()
                    VStack(alignment: .center) {
                        customTextView(with: service.frame(in: .title))
                            .padding(.bottom, 8)
                        customTextView(with: service.frame(in: .genres))
                            .padding(.bottom, 8)
                            .frame(width: gr.size.width * 0.8)
                        Text("\(service.movie?.releaseDate ?? "")")
                            .font(.title3)
                            .padding(.bottom, 8)
                        if service.movie?.tagline != "" {
                            Text("\"\(service.movie?.tagline ?? "")\"")
                                .font(.title3)
                                .padding(.bottom, 8)
                                .frame(alignment: .center)
                        }
                        customTextView(with: service.frame(in: .overview))
                            .padding(.bottom, 8)
                            .frame(width: gr.size.width * 0.8)
                        Text("\(service.credits?.cast.map({ $0.name }).joined(separator: " - ") ?? "")")
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .frame(width: gr.size.width)
    }
}
}

extension ContentView {
@ViewBuilder
func customTextView(with words: [Word]) -> some View {
    VStack {
        LazyHGrid(rows: rows, spacing: 2) {
            ForEach(words) { word -> AnyView in
                if word.isFramed {
                    return AnyView(
                        Text("\(word.text)")
                            .padding(2)
                            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4))
                            .overlay {
                                if word.isTouched {
                                    Text("\(word.text.count)")
                                        .foregroundColor(Color.cyan)
                                }
                            }
                    )
                }
                
                return AnyView(Text(word.text))
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code for the `Service` class and what data you pass into it?

Comment: The Service just retrieve data from an API. I split string into Word array with isFramed as true and isTouched as false for the moment. I need help for the UI of my customTextView grid actually :(

Answer (score 0):

Do you think you could post your code so that we can see what you have done?

Comment: I've shared it :)

Comment: Please ask for code in Question comments as this section is limited to answers only.